# How to display something on flexbox div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to display something on flexbox div?
I've got container and in this container is box - bigBox where I've got another boxes - boxA (fullscreen). Eveyrthing works and I can simply scroll down, but I would like to put little div in the center of boxA and it's impossible.

```css
.container {
        overflow: auto;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        display:flex;
    }
    
    .bigBox{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .boxA {
        background: white;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class = "container>
    <div class = "bigBox">
            
            <div class ="boxA"><center><img src="img.jpeg" style= "width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                </center>
            </div>
    <div class ="boxA"><center><img src="img.jpeg" style= "width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                </center>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I would suggest you posting the whole markup and styles, since anything inside that DOM will affect the behavior of something inside that DOM

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `center` tag and if you want the image to be centered don't give it a `width` and `height` of 100%.

```css
.container {
        overflow: auto;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        display:flex;
    }
    
    .bigBox{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .boxA {
        background: white;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    img{
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class = "container>
    <div class = "bigBox">
        <div class ="boxA">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-700-700-9.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class ="boxA">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/cats-q-c-700-700-9.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I did it like this and image doesn't fit in the box - it adapts it's own dimensions.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't fit in the box". Is the image too large?

Comment: Yes, it is too large.

Comment: Updated my answer with height:100% for image and set height of 50px for boxA. Now if you change the height of boxA, image will size accordingly.

Comment: Right now, it is too small.

Comment: You can't adjust the height yourself? What do you want it to be?

Comment: Size is okay right now, sorry for mistake. But I just want to display another thing in the centre of boxA.

Comment: I have no idea what you want.